# How to use different ids in Xapian?

Tags: python, xapian

I'm trying to implement a search with Xapian. My documents have its own ids, that are strings. I already do as the tutorail says:

```
db.replace_document(doc.docno, doc_x)
```

where doc.docno is the string that identifies the document.
But when I search:

```
for match in enquire.get_mset(0, 10):
    print match.document.get_docid()
```

The docid recovered is just a simple number.
Anyone know if I should have to do something else?

Comment: Hopefully my answer helps; if you have further issues getting this working, someone can usually help either on our mailing lists or on IRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xapian document ids are always numbers, however it provides a mechanism for you to address documents by term as well as by id. So `replace_document()` and `delete_document()` can be given a string, as you have done, and they will find all existing documents matching that term, and remove them from the database. `replace_document()` will then create a new document, re-using the lowest matching (numeric) document id, or using a new id if no documents match.

The [documentation for this variant of `replace_document()`](https://xapian.org/docs/apidoc/html/classXapian_1_1WritableDatabase.html#a43c4630ec482508667e9ca539f19cbf0) says:

> One common use is to allow UIDs from another system to easily be mapped to terms in Xapian. Note that this method doesn't automatically add unique_term as a term, so you'll need to call `document.add_term(unique_term)` first when using `replace_document()` in this way.

If you're using `QueryParser`, or in some other way are following the [term prefixing convention](https://xapian.org/docs/omega/termprefixes.html) that a lot of Xapian systems follow, then it's common to use `Q` as the prefix. This means you probably want to do the following before you call `replace_document()`:

`doc_x.add_term('X' + doc.docno)`

Then, when you query the database, you'll need to get your document id out again. You can do this by reading from the termlist, but that's a bit fiddly so it's more common to store your "external" id (external to Xapian) in the `Document` data. (I often store JSON in there, to provide some scope for growth of what I need; for instance it can sometimes be useful to include all the information needed to render a search result in the document data.)

This approach is covered in [Xapian's FAQ on working with existing unique ids](https://trac.xapian.org/wiki/FAQ/UniqueIds), particularly the second section, "Using a term for the external unique id".